# This php resizing code is only formatting certain images and not other ones

Tags: php, image

This code is resizing all of the jpeg images to what I want, but I have a few images that skip over the resizing and simply are uploaded in there original size. Is there something I am missing or overlooking in the resizing function?(photo details will be with the code)

I have tried multiple images and they all work expect for three of the test images(details below).

```
<?php
function resize_image($file, $max_resolution){

    if(file_exists($file)){
        $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

        //resolution
        $original_width = imagesx($original_image);
        $original_height = imagesy($original_image);

        //try width first
        $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_width;
        $new_width = $max_resolution;
        $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;

        if($new_height > $max_resolution) {
            $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_height;
            $new_height = $max_resolution;
            $new_width = $orignial_width * ratio;
        }
            if($original_image){
 $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image,$original_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$original_width,$original_height); 
        imagejpeg($new_image, $file, 90);


        }

    }

}
    if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['image']['name']);
        $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        resize_image($file, "500"); 

        echo "<img src='$file'/>";
    }
?>

<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="file" name="image"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="post">
</form>
```

Results:
This is the image that skips the resize and goes into the folder as the same size with no alteration:
Myron_3.jpg - Kind: JPEG, size 334kb, Dimensions: 2304 X 3456

These two are coming out with the expected results:
IMG_0610.JPG - size: 2 MB, dimension: 3024 X 4032. After resizing:
Size 46kb

test_4.jpg - size: 56 kb, dimension: 959 X 957, after resize: 46kb

Comment: Typo? `$new_width = $orignial_width * ratio;`

Comment: You can save disk space by setting JPEG density to ~80 rather than 90 as that is still indistinguishable to the human eye.

Comment: try adding an else after `if($original_image)` and try errorlogging if the file that is not resizing is going inside there.